# Count commandline arguments of parent ssh process... on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, tmux

I make heavy use of [this technique](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451534/196978) get a Linux tmux console.  The intent here is that the `Match...exec` does not execute the RemoteCommand when I'm doing an `ssh host command`, so remote execution doesn't get broken.

However, the answer linked above is specific to a linux ssh client.  I haven't been able to figure out how to do it on Windows.

Can you write a Windows commandline that will give a nonzero errorcode if *the parent openssh process* has only a single commandline argument?

[Edit: this question has been modified to correct my initial misunderstanding that the Match Exec was run in a *sibling* process.]

Comment: **It's not a sibling.** `Match exec ...` runs as a _child_ of `ssh`. The answer you linked doesn't do what you say, but [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499562/59699) does use `$PPID` in the exec process to reference its PARENT process which is the `ssh` process. In Windows you can get ParentProcessID and (then) its CommandLine using powershell; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33911332 and https://superuser.com/questions/884785 . But I don't think it has a way to parse Unix-style options, so if you need that to be correct it'll be a good deal of work.

Comment: Thanks very much!  Entirely unintentional application of Cunningham's law there.  I don't need to parse the options, just count the arguments, so I ought to be able to make it work.

Comment: Revised the question per your comment, and posted a partial answer below.  I'm stumped for getting my one-liner running in a Match Exec though.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer here, I think.  I'm weak with PowerShell, but this sequence of commands gives the wordcount of the PPID's commandline.

```
$PPID = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$PID).ParentProcessId
$CMD = wmic process where "ProcessID = $PPID" get commandline /value
$WC = ($CMD | measure-object -Word).Words
$WC
```

The following single-liner returns a "fail" errorlevel if the PPID has more than 2 words:

> `if ((wmic process where "ProcessID = $((Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter ProcessId=$PID).ParentProcessId)" get commandline /value| measure-object -Word).Words -gt 2) { exit 1 }`

However, I can't figure out how to shoehorn that into an ssh `Match Exec` given the levels of nested quotes.  Putting it into a .PS1 file seems to result in ssh hanging at script exit.  Advice welcome!